# parenting problem

Tags: objects, transforms, shortcut, object-mode

please I try to make a parent between two objects, I select the two object and press ( ctrl + p ), but the parenting menu does not appear, and the program reject to make parenting

Comment: Hi :). How about using Object > Parent? (in case your shortcuts got changed)

Comment: also, are you sure you are in Object mode?

Comment: yes I have tried to go to object then parent and the parent thank you, but the child do no follow father , desipte i selected the father ( last object )

Comment: yes I am in object mode